# Why pypy is not recognizing my python 2.7/3.4 modules and packages?

Tags: python-2.7, memory, python-3.4, pypy

I am running my python codes using either `python script.py` or `python3 script.py`. (The first one is based on 2.7 and the second one based on 3.4). However, recently I am working on a code that is pretty demanding in terms of computational expense. I am not an expert in python in order to speed up my code (which uses alot of other routines all compatible with both versions of python 2.7 and 3.4). When the `.hdf5` input file of my function inside the code is on the order of 1 Mbi, the code is running and producing the result even though slowly. But when the `.hdf5` input file of the function is on the order of 1 Gbi, the code almost never proceeds to the end and I am ending up with a "MemoryError:"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 29, in <module>
    gizmo.analysis.Image.plot_image(part, 'gas', 'mass.hydrogen.neutral', 'histogram', [0,1],[0,1,2], distance_max, distance_bin_width_Gas, distance_bin_number, part_indices=part_indices, write_plot=write_plot, plot_directory=plot_directory, background_color=background_color, use_column_units=True)
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Projects/PaperMaterials/DM_Dominated_Objects/NewFolder2/covering_fractions/Simulations/gizmo/gizmo_analysis.py", line 817, in plot_image
    weights = part[spec_name].prop(weight_prop_name, part_indices)
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Projects/PaperMaterials/DM_Dominated_Objects/NewFolder2/covering_fractions/Simulations/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 145, in prop
    self.prop(property_name.replace('mass.', 'massfraction.'), indices))
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Projects/PaperMaterials/DM_Dominated_Objects/NewFolder2/covering_fractions/Simulations/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 157, in prop
    values = (1 - self.prop('massfraction', indices)[:, 0] -
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Projects/PaperMaterials/DM_Dominated_Objects/NewFolder2/covering_fractions/Simulations/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 65, in prop
    return self[property_name][indices]
MemoryError
```

After doing some search on this website, I noticed that I can run python codes using pypy for example to speed them up. Since I am using Fedora 21 (32 bit) OS which comes with a pypy 2.4 version in its repository, I was able to install this version of pypy successfully. However, when I try to run my code using the command line `pypy myscript.py` instead of the ones mentioned above, I am left with error message:

> File "app_main.py", line 75, in run_toplevel   File "myscript.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import numpy as np ImportError: No module named numpy

It seems that pypy does not recognize all the python modules and packages including this particular one.

What would be your best suggestion for me given the fact that I would like to stick with Fedora 21 Linux distribution such that all the python modules and packages be recognized by pypy resulting in faster codes?

I can post what `myscript.py` is but I am not sure if that would be helpful at all given the fact that I am using lots of other routines in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPy 2.4 is a rather outdated version which contains no support for numpy (even if you tried to install it separately).

In any case it is very unlikely that even a brand-new version of PyPy would reduce the memory usage of a numpy-heavy program.

If you're hitting MemoryError at the scale of ~1-3GB of data in a single process, on a 32-bit OS, then it seems clear to me that you need a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I was able in the short term to modify my code by not reading all the contents in the .hdf5 file (depending on the functions minimal input data) so that a 32 bit operating system could be able to manage the memory albeit slowly but without loss of precision in the final results. However, I did have to move to a 64-bit OS in the long run in which I have no longer that issue.

Comment: I noticed that I didn't answer the exact question you posed: you need to install every package specifically for PyPy, just like installing one for Python 2.7 doesn't automatically makes it available to Python 3.4.  Use "pypy -m ensurepip" and then "pypy -m pip install NAME" to use Python's own packaging system instead of your distribution's (because the latter, likely, doesn't contain many module for pypy).